# Probability union bound from Aaronson's book

Tags: probability

This is from http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec7.html :

"Third, an immediate consequence of the above, called the union bound:

Pr[A or B] ≤ Pr[A] + Pr[B].

Or in English: if you're unlikely to drown and you're unlikely to get struck by lightning,     then chances are you'll neither drown nor get struck by lightning, regardless of whether getting struck by lightning makes you more or less likely to drown."

Can someone please explain how we get the result mentioned in the english example by applying the union bound? I.e. what are the events etc. What confuses me is the following: if we take A to be "getting drown" and B to be "getting struck by lightning" then isn't Pr[not(A or B)] = Pr[not(A) and not(B)] what we want? How do we bound that?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it becomes clear if you draw Venn's diagram: 
$$
P( A \cup B ) = P(A) +P(B)-P(A \cap B) \leq P(A) +P(B)
$$
because $P(A \cap B) \geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that. What I don't understand is how he uses it in the english example that he provides.